# Unable to go back to previous view controller

Tags: xcode, cocoa, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am using storyboards. From ViewController1, I segue to ViewController2 using a modal segue programmatically:
`[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"ViewController2" sender: self];`.

At the end of ViewController2 execution, I want to go back to the first view controller using∫br>`[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`
and receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.

Reading the numerous articles on this issue, the statement seems to be that the initial view controller is deallocated. However none of the articles I found explains how to prevent this deallocation and how to anyway come back.

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `self` for the dismiss.  Use `self.presentingViewController`.